# GCP Billing Account Suspicious Activity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I got a warning about suspicious activity in my GCP billing account. GCP asked me to verify my payment method (credit card) by uploading the photo of the credit card and government issued ID card. I uploaded them then my account got suspended without reason. Anybody knows about this or knows who should I contact regarding this issue?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, *StackOverflow community can do nothing with issues related to billing*.

Please have a look at the documentation [Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing):

> **All Google Cloud accounts get free billing and payments support.** This
> page tells you how to contact Cloud Billing Support if you need help
> with your Cloud Billing account, and shows you where to get more
> information about managing your billing account.
>
> Cloud Billing Support is available in several regions and languages.
> For information about support availability, see [Google Cloud Support
> Plans](https://cloud.google.com/support).

**To solve your issue** you should contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support), it's free of charge for all billing related questions as a part of Basic support plan.